# Double check mark similar to Whatsapp's read status

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

How to make a double check marks in UILabel through
unicode chack mark (U+2713), without any image

To do this with Unicode is not a problem, how to make it similar to whatsapp's [read status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sP7rK.png)? how to do letter spacing or remove space beetween two unicode symbol?

Comment: Check maybe with `NSAttributedString` and play with its `NSAttributedStringKey.kern` attribute?

Comment: Thanks @larme, this is what I needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this using `NSAttributedStringKey.kern`…

```
let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 30))
label.backgroundColor = .white

label.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: "✓✓", attributes: [.kern: -6])
```

[image]

From [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring/key/1527891-kern)…

> The value of this attribute is an `NSNumber` object containing a floating-point value. This value specifies the number of points by which to adjust kern-pair characters. Kerning prevents unwanted space from occurring between specific characters and depends on the font. The value 0 means kerning is disabled. The default value for this attribute is 0.

Comment: How about a double-check symbol with the ticks stacked on top of each other vertically, as in WhatsApp?

Comment: Sounds like a job for Photoshop